# Adding quote character in minting removes colorbox highlighting

Tags: color, minted, quotation

To highlight a single word in a block of code, I use

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=@@]{scheme}
'(@\colorbox{yellow}{cat}@ dog bat)))
\end{minted}
```

to get

[image]

but when I put a `'` before `cat`,

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=@@]{scheme}
'(@\colorbox{yellow}{'cat}@ dog bat)))
\end{minted}
```

the colorbox highlighting breaks:

[image]

How can I use the `'` character while using `colorbox` highlighting in a `minted` code block?

## Edit

I should add that I cannot use `\textsinglequote` as in:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=@@]{scheme}
'(@\colorbox{yellow}{\textsinglequote cat}@ dog bat)))
\end{minted}
```

because while rendering it inserts a space between `'` and `cat`,

[image]

which makes the syntax of the Scheme program being rendered invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `\textquotesingle{}` (note the pair of empty curly braces):

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=@@]{scheme}
'(@\colorbox{yellow}{\textquotesingle{}cat}@ dog bat)))
\end{minted}
```

to get what was desired:

[image]

Although I still don't understand why just using `'` doesn't work.